# How to tag an image as `latest` using Docker Buildx

Tags: docker, buildx

I'm using Docker Buildx to build my images to multiple architectures, as I'm building them on a MacOS (arm64) but want them to run on a Cloud Run (amd64).

I'm running:

```
$ docker buildx build \
    --push \
    --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 \
    --tag stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api:1.0.0 \
    --file carts-api/docker/Dockerfile \
    ./carts-api
```

It builds and publishes my images to Docker Hub. But then, I want to have a tag `latest` pointing to this latest image too. Tried:

```
$ docker tag \
  stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api:1.0.0 \
  stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api:latest

$ docker push \
  stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api:latest
```

But I get this:

```
Error response from daemon: No such image: stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api:1.0.0
The push refers to repository [docker.io/stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api
```

It feels like Buildx builds the image, publishes it, but don't create the local image.

How can I publish a `latest` tag pointing to my latest build using Docker Buildx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass `--tag` multiple times:

```bash
docker buildx build \
    --push \
    --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 \
    --tag stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api:1.0.0 \
    --tag stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api:latest \
    --file carts-api/docker/Dockerfile \
    ./carts-api
```

Otherwise, if you need to retag an image that is already pushed to a registry, there are multiple 3rd party tools that do this directly with registry API calls that avoids the need to pull any image layers. Those tools include crane from Google, oras from Microsoft, skopeo from RedHat, and regctl from myself. Each of these includes an image copy command, which when the repo name is the same, is effectively a retag.

I'd avoid outputting and tagging the image on the local docker engine since, unless you have enabled the currently experimental containerd management for images, the image is first dereferenced to a single platform image, losing the ability to run on both arm64 and amd64.

Comment: Thanks! When you mean it loses the ability to run on both archs, you mean locally? 'Cause locally I'm only interested in running arm64 anyway (as I'm using MacOS), and only need the amd64 so Cloud Run pulls that version to run it instead.

Comment: @StanleySathler An image can be a multi-platform image list on a registry. When you pull it to your docker engine, or skip the push, current versions of docker (without some experimental settings) will pull a single platform (your local platform). If you were to tag and push that back to the registry, the new tag would only have your single platform image. When you instead tag with the `docker buildx build` command and push directly to the registry, you avoid all of the docker engine platform dereferencing.

Answer (score 2):

`--push` is an alias for `--output=registry`, meaning that `buildx` will export the image directly to the registry.

You can remove `--push` from your build command and push the image manually later or you can specify multiple output targets like (works since build version 0.13.0):

```
docker buildx build \
    -o type=docker \
    -o type=registry \
    --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 \
    --tag stanleysathler/terraform-starter-carts-api:1.0.0 \
    --file carts-api/docker/Dockerfile \
    ./carts-api
```

For more details see: https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/buildx/build/#output